# vector graphics in MS VSTS Wiki

Tags: svg, azure-devops, vector-graphics

Using the latest online version from VSTS.

Is it somehow possible to use vector graphics in the vsts wiki?

I know I can't upload a `.svg` as attachment (only png, jpeg and gif) but is there any other approach?
In the end, it is just static file serving. Using markdown, I can use any url to a public `.svg` and the image gets rendered correctly using the VSTS wiki. But I can't upload the graphic on my own. Also it has to be uploaded inside VSTS, a public file hosting location is not allowed.
My Idea was to upload the vector graphic inside the `code` section and inside the wiki to reference to the corresponding `.svg`. But I cannot or simply don't know how to get the full url to the `.svg`.
Any hints for that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the markdown for [image syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/collaborate/markdown-guidance?view=vsts#images) (`![Text](URL)`) to show vector graphics on wiki page (but the xml format hass not been supported yet).

While to get the url for a local .svg file, you need to hosted .svg file to a place with http protocol supported. But it seems there has no free site to hosted .svg files. And you can also refer the post [free and convenient svg hosting](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rec.photo.digital/vCIiBnV8OKI).

Comment: Yeahhh, what means "not support vector graphics". Vector graphics can't be attached to the wiki I know that, however you can insert a markdown image tag pointing to public available `.svg` image and it will be rendered. So maybe somehow upload it in the code section of VSTS and get a full url to `.svg` file?

Comment: I would say it does. Just try it with: `![test](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fd/Ghostscript_Tiger.svg)` in the wiki, i definitely see the image.

Comment: @Leo Thanks for reminder. And I tested just now, it can works. But it seems there has no place to host .svg files for free. Or it's read-only permission for other sites (like https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/).